# Since the latest update, I can seem to run multiple tests in parallel from the pytest feature of the green checks next to the test

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pytest tests used to be available for running them from the green checks next to the code (UI) parallelly, but now when clicking on the checks, it will only run the first test you click on, but no test after that will run. It will only work if you wait for the execution to end and then click.

---